# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (using .format())

Tags: python, dataframe, syntax, format

I have used `format` in Python many times, but this one I am having trouble.

The solution should be simple, but I'm not getting it...

Here is the code:

```
test_list = df.groupby(['gender', 'admitted'])['student_id'].count()

print('The quantity of female students are {}.'.format(test_list[0] + test_list[1])
```

The output of `test_list` is:

```
gender  admitted
female  False       183
        True         74
male    False       125
        True        118
Name: student_id, dtype: int64
```

So, `test_list[0]` is 183 and `test_list[1]` is 74.

The result expected from print is:

```
The quantity of female students are 257.
```

Comment: Missing closing ')' for the print statement

Comment: Omg!!!! I spent precious minutes for these simple error. Thanks a lot. I am ashamed, lol!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing ")" in your `print` statement. Because of that, the parser reached the end of the file before it expected to, thus raising an `EOFError`.

All you need to do is change it to this:

```
test_list = df.groupby(['gender', 'admitted'])['student_id'].count()

print('The quantity of female students are {}.'.format(test_list[0] + test_list[1]))
```